# Fatal error: Cannot use ::class with dynamic class name in /vendor/laminas/laminas-mail/src/Message.php on line 394

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, php-8.1

I am trying to upgrade Magento 2.4.3 Adobe Cloud version to 2.4.4 and I was successfully update the composer.json with necessary changes.
Also I was able to run the di:compile command successfully. Now when I am trying to access my website I am getting this error

`Fatal error: Cannot use ::class with dynamic class name in /var/www/html/vendor/laminas/laminas-mail/src/Message.php on line 394`

Does anyone faced same issue?

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that your version of PHP 8.0+. PHP version in my CLI was 8.1, but my server hasn't changed the version to 8.1(was 7.4), it was just the CLI version due to my alias. That's why I didn't got any results after debugging.

P.S. I faced the same issue in the Laminas\Http\Headers on line 162.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add php version, for example, php8.1 bin/magento s:s:d -f or php8.1 bin/magento s:d:c

Comment: Not formatted, i am not sure, if it helps